# yii rbac acf multiple roles and params

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac, yii2-rbac

So I have an action which I need multiple `permissions` to have access to.

(for example `manageUsers` (admin) and `manageCompanyUsers` (company manager))

`access` behaviour `in controller` has `rule` like:

```
'allow' => true,
'actions' => ['index'],
'roles' => [
   'manageUsers',
   'manageCompanyUsers'
],
'roleParams' => ['company' => 'some id']
```

1) how do I pass different params for different roles in it? (with this code it passes `company` to `manageCompanyUsers` anyway)

2) how can I make sure that if `manageUsers` is a child of `manageCompanyUsers` and `user` has `manageUsers` assigned directly to not trigger `manageCompanyUsers` rules (it triggers now)

Answer (score 0):

Make several rules with different params and roles applied to each:

```
[ //rule1
  'allow' => true,
  'actions' => ['index'],
  'roles' => [
     'manageUsers',
  ],
  'roleParams' => ['company' => 'some id']
],
[ //rule2
  'allow' => true,
  'actions' => ['index'],
  'roles' => [
     'manageCompanyUsers',
  ],
  'roleParams' => ['some' => 'other id']
],
```